# boolean masking inner dimensions of ndarray using same mask

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have a 3d ndarray and I want to remove all values of lower dimensions given the same mask efficiently and cleanly. Hopefully code below explains what I'm looking for better:

```
arr   = np.random.randint(0,3, (5, 3,4))
bmask = arr[0] > 0 

#######
#Naive way
########
result = []
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    result.append(arr[i][bmask])
result = np.stack(result)

####### 
# Better Way
#######
better_way = ???????


assert np.all(result == better_way)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a colon for the first dimension, and use `bmask` for the rest, like:

```
better_way = arr[:, bmask]
```